# methods to handle cache data in memory through multi servers

Tags: caching, apache-kafka, server, redis, rabbitmq

I'd like to get rid of a cron working every 20 seconds to load data from database in order to cache data in memory on servers. I know it looks pretty bad so I would like to redesign for that.

I have two ideas.

Firstly, I might be able to use `message queue` like `kafka`, `rabbitMQ` and etc. I used to use `rabbitMQ` to sort out this problem with different projects. That would work.

By the way, the second method was come up with, which is `redis` pub/sub. It might actually work. Then I will be able to either convert all in-memory-cache into redis-cache or just update
in-memory-cache when subscribing.

Are both good approaches? Is there any better way to achieve my goal? I have to consider multi server updates at once.

Comment: Why do you still use pub/sub if you use Redis?

Comment: @Gawain well... redis just has that feature and it can be also what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

For in memory cache, the most important point is to make data update to date between multiple servers. And there are advantages and disadvantages for MQ and Redis solution.

For MQ solution, the advantage is you cache will distributed to your application servers, which can reduce the load pressure for cache(with load balancer in front).

Disadvantage is you need to make sure you cache for each servers are synchronized. As MQ listeners are asynchronous, there may have delays for different servers. And if you server lost connection to MQ, you data will also be out of date. Also if you cached to much data, your application memory can be booming since each of your server maintains a whole cache replica.

For Redis, it will always use single data source so synchronization will not be a problem. And you don't need to use pub/sub, just load the data into Redis.

But Redis will have a huge load pressure since all servers will query cache from same Redis.

So you can compare the advantages and disadvantages for each solution based on your case.

Comment: As you said, Redis has to query data. In my case, latency is pretty import so I would take message queue instead of Redis. Thank you !

Comment: Yes Redis will gain the latency due to network. Also you can use memcached  for in memory local cache which have more powerful management for cache.

Comment: I decided to select `Redis pub/sub` and will use memcached in local memory.